# Input checkBox como checked

Tags: html, jquery, input, checkbox

¿Como le pongo un valor a un `input` de tipo `checkbox` mediante `jquery`?

```
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo MultiSucursal es obligatorio." id="MultiSucursal" name="MultiSucursal" type="checkbox" value="False">
```

Estoy utilizando jquery donde obtengo el dato si esta checked o no.

```
$('#frmContactoEdit input[name=MultiSucursal]').var($(e.relatedTarget).data('multisucursal'));
```

Con este botón obtengo los datos que quiero a editar.

```
<button 
 type="button" 
 class="btn btn-info" 
 id="4116" 
 data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#ContactoEdit" 
 data-cliente="4116" 
 data-sucursal="Oficinas Administrativas" 
 data-nombre="Maria" 
 data-correo="" 
 data-departamento="Produccion" 
 data-puesto="Auxiliar Produccion" 
 data-telefonooficina="" 
 data-telefonomovil="" 
 data-multisucursal="False">
 <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar el atributo `checked` que tiene el elemento `input check` para setear los elementos. Esto en base a una combinación de javascript puro y Jquery, a mí al menos está es la manera más fácil que encuentro

```js
function ponercheck(btn){
let e = {relatedTarget: btn}; //solo para test

$('#frmContactoEdit input[name=MultiSucursal]')[0].checked= $(e.relatedTarget).data('multisucursal')==true;


//solo con jquery
//$('#frmContactoEdit input[name=MultiSucursal]').attr("checked",$(e.relatedTarget).data('multisucursal'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="frmContactoEdit">

<input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo MultiSucursal es obligatorio." id="MultiSucursal" name="MultiSucursal" type="checkbox" value="False">

<button 
 type="button" 
 data-multisucursal="true"
 onclick="ponercheck(this)"
 >
true
</button>

<button 
 type="button" 
 data-multisucursal="false"
 onclick="ponercheck(this)"
 >
 false
 </button>
 
 <button 
 type="button" 
 data-multisucursal=" cualquier cosa"
 onclick="ponercheck(this)"
 >
 cualquier cosa
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: sí el `data-multisucursal` me sale `false`, aún me lo pone como `checked`

Comment: @Luis Prueba nuevamente

Comment: Gracias, me funciono...